# Rails sort list without using model column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following table in my view:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
  <th><h3>Department</h3></th>
  <th><h3>Average Rating</h3></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <%@unique_dept.each do |prod| %>
  <td><p class="text-center"><h4><%= prod.dept.capitalize %></h4></p></td>
  <td><p class="text-center"><h4><%= RatingSet.avg_rating_by_dept(prod.dept) %></h4></p></td>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
  </table>
```

My Controller action:

```
 def index
     @unique_dept = Product.find_by_sql("SELECT dept FROM products WHERE dept <> '' GROUP BY dept")
  end
```

My Model Methods:

```
 def self.avg_rating_by_dept(dept)
    RatingSet.joins(:products).where("dept = ?","#{dept}").average(:product_rating).to_f.round(2)
  end
```

How can I sort `Department` and `Average Rating` since they are not associated with a column in my model?

Comment: Sort by what? am i missing something, but couldn't you just do :
`prod.dept.sort.capitalize` ?

Comment: A note, your `<tr>` tag is outside from your `each` loop. Have you tried the query just with `SELECT dept FROM products WHERE dept <> '' GROUP BY dept ORDER BY dept` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
@unique_dept = Product.find_by_sql("SELECT dept FROM products WHERE dept <> '' GROUP BY dept") 
@unique_dept = @unique_dept.sort_by{ |prod| prod.dept }
```

For the rating do

```
RatingSet.joins(:products).where("dept = ?","#{dept}").average(:product_rating).to_f.round(2).order('products.product_rating')
```